# Class has or is using name 'SafeUrl' from external module but cannot be named

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-cli, angular2-aot

I'm using `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` to put links to blobURL's on the page. This works just fine as long as I don't AoT compile the project.

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  sanitize(url: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }
}
```

The sanitize function takes a URL like this:

```
blob:http://localhost:4200/7c1d7221-aa0e-4d98-803d-b9be6400865b
```

If I use AoT compilation I get this error message:

> Module build failed: Error: /.../src/app/app.component.ts (18,3):
>   Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name
>   'SafeUrl' from external module
>   "/.../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service"
>   but cannot be named.)

I'm using CLI with Angular 2.1.0

Anybody knows how I can circumvent this problem? Or should it be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it seems I had to add a return type of `SafeUrl` to the method

```
  sanitize(url: string):SafeUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }
```

Big thanks to [alxhub](https://github.com/alxhub)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was initiating an attribute like this :

```
public img64 = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.base64Image);
```

Resulting in the same error.

Thanks to @mottosson I got it right (just add the type SafeUrl):

```
public img64: SafeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.base64Image);
```