# Cannot find name 'SafeUrl'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

I am trying to remove the unsafe warning from the console I added bypassSecurityTrustUrl method. But I am getting the error

**user.component.ts**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NavParams,Platform,ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl:`<a [href]="sanitize('sms:'+user.mobile_no)" class="anchor-default">Text</a>`,
    styles:[`
        .anchor-black{color: #000; font-size: 2.4rem;}
        .anchor-default {text-decoration: none;}
        .custom-margin{margin-left:10px;}
        .anchor-right{float:right;padding-top:2px;}
        .text-content{text-overflow: ellipsis; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:12px;}
    `]
})

export class User implements OnInit {

    public user;

    public bStandings:boolean = false;

    constructor(
        public navParams:NavParams, 
        public viewCtrl:ViewController,
        public platform:Platform,
        public domSanitizer:DomSanitizer
    ) {}

    sanitize(url:string){
        return this.sanitizeUrl(url);
    }

    private sanitizeUrl(url:string):SafeUrl {
        this.bStandings = true;
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
    }

}
```

**Related Question:**
[Class has or is using name 'SafeUrl' from external module but cannot be named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320055/class-has-or-is-using-name-safeurl-from-external-module-but-cannot-be-named)

Anyone please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize `user.mobile_no`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just import `SafeUrl` as well:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```